# Retrieving files with grep that contain !#abc

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to display files that contain

```
!#abc
```

I tried like this

```
grep -l '!#abc'
```

but it doesn't work. Why?

Also, when I try something like

```
echo "#!a"
```

it retrieves

```
echo "#alias".
```

Can someone, please explain me what is happening here? What does #! in fact represent?

Comment: ' vs. ". bashism. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash

Answer (score 0):

you have to write

```
grep \\!\\#abc <file>
```

you basically have to escape both the `#` and the `!`, this two characters have special meaning in pretty much any shell, read the manual of your shell to know more about them .

Comment: Since they tagged bash, a [link to the history section of the bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/History-Interaction.html#History-Interaction) would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the grep: `grep -l '!#abc'` needs also a list of files to process:

```
grep -l '!#abc' ./*
```

works in all the files in the present directory.

The echo: `echo "#!a"` needs a little more of quoting, like:

```
$ echo '#!a'
#!a

$ echo '#'\!'a'
#!a

$ echo '#'\!a
#!a

$ echo "#!"a
#!a

$ echo "#"'!a'
#!a

$ echo $'#!a'
#!a
```

The '#' is the comment character. From `LESS=+'/^ *COMMENTS' man bash`:

> COMMENTS
>
> ```
> In a non-interactive shell, or an interactive shell in which the  
> interactive_comments option to the shopt builtin is enabled (see SHELL  
> BUILTIN COMMANDS below), a word beginning with # causes that word and  
> all remaining characters on that line to be  ignored. An interactive  
> shell without the interactive_comments option enabled does not allow  
> comments. The interactive_comments option is on by default in  
> interactive shells.
> ```

Anything that follows it in one line is considered 'a comment' and not processed, like:

```
$ echo one # two three
one
```

If you want to avoid its effect, you need to quote it, or place it just after some other non-blank character:

```
$ echo one t# wo three
one t# wo three
```

---

The `!` is the history "key character".
Just the tip of the Iceberg: From `LESS=+'/^ *HISTORY EXPANSION' man bash`:

> HISTORY EXPANSION
>   History expansions are introduced by the appearance of the history expansion  character, which  is  !  by  default.  Only backslash () and single quotes can quote the history expansion character, but the history expansion character is also treated as quoted if it immediately precedes the closing double quote in a double-quoted string.

---

So, for your last question: `What does #! in fact represent?`.

The answer is `It depends.`
Depends on the surrounding characters as well.
Depends if it is quoted (and how is quoted) or not.
And depends if it has preceding white space and/or trailing white space.

If correctly quoted, just the same characters.
If not quoted with a leading space: a comment.
If not quoted, no leading space, no trailing space: an history expansion.
If not quoted, no leading space, with a trailing space: the characters.

That, of course, is assuming that the options

```
shopt -p interactive_comments
shopt -po history
```

Are both set. Each controls the respective character (`#` and `!`) in interactive shells. In non-interactive shells, the comment character is always enforced, and history expansion is almost always not activated.